# Web API 2 throw exception on invalid datetimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

I'm sending dates from a JavaScript client to and ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller as a POST.

If I send some string that is not a date it will silently be transformed to `DateTime` Min value. I assume it is defaulting to default(`DateTime`).

I would like to throw an exception before going inside my controller action.
What would be the best approach?

**What I have tried:**

I've tried creating a subclass of `DateTimeConverterBase` and adding it to `HttpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters`. But only the `WriteJson` function ever gets called. Never `ReadJson` according to my breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an action and add it to your pipeline, that checks ModelState.IsValid and throws a 400 status back to the client.

Comment: ModelState.IsValid returns true if I check inside my method. :/
Would an action make a difference?

Comment: No it wouldn’t make a difference. Model binding occurs the same either way.

Comment: I assume it thinks it got a good DateTime after it was set to Min.

Comment: Try marking the property [required] I’m wondering if the field name you are sending is not matching.

Comment: Thank you! Field name was correct. But needed Required to handle the case where date is undefined or null. ModelState.IsValid took care of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) before to achieve model validation in web API. This is a nice solution in that it's aspect-oriented so is neatly out of the way.

This is also the way the old MVC did model validation, and it works the same way. You simply apply the annotation syntax as declarative attributes on your model:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] // or something similar
public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

Then you can access the provided [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) static instance which automatically becomes available to your controller action by referencing the assembly containing your annotated models. You can then pass this into the appropriate [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse%28System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary%29) of the CreateErrorResponse() extension, and web API will take care of the error response for you:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // bad request
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

> I would like to throw an exception before going inside my controller action

If you really want to do this then you can implement the same validation in an [action filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) by implementing [OnActionExecuting()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext)). I've not done this and to be honest I can't really see the benefit other than keeping your controllers skinny.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the action filter.
I think I might want this for all posts (you see any reasons not to?), so it should avoid me some typing.

Comment: @simmenilsson to be honest I can't see the benefit of doing it in  filter. Validation is a business concern and therefore belongs in the controller I think. Also you'll be able to test more easily by extending your controller tests

Answer (score 0):

send date as string from js code. In the web api controller, try `datetime.parse` or `datetime.tryparse` as per your date format.

e.g.

```
   public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string date)
   {
     DateTime dt = new DateTime();
     if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dt))
     {
          return BadRequest("incorrect input");

     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a workaround, but I would like to handle it once and for all. Not add code for every DateTime property in the project.

Comment: you may try a service to parse datetime. Inject in a controller where you need. This would avoid code rewrite.